# Why doesn't do-release-upgrade offer to upgrade to 17.10 without -d flag?

Tags: upgrade, updates

Why does a simple `do-release-upgrade` not upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10 if [Ubuntu 17.10 is officially released](https://www.ubuntu.com/). I have to add the `-d` flag which treats 17.10 like a development version. It doesn't have any side effects, i.e. the upgrade is performed as expected, but it doesn't seem to be correct and most users might not catch this and complain that the upgrade to 17.10 doesn't work. As far as I remember the same happened when 17.04 was released.

Does `do-release-upgrade` have an update function I'm missing and which isn't listed in the manpage?

Comment: There's a line in your `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` file ending in `Prompt=`.  If that says `lts`, you won't be offered these interim upgrades.  For that, you need `normal`.

Comment: It was already `normal`. The referenced post is helpful, though.

Comment: The short answer is because Canonical wishes to differentiate between LTS and non-LTS and they do this in do-release-upgrade by marking non-LTS releases as "developmental" http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html . I am not sure if the behavior you are seeing today is intentional, ie they decided to mark all non-LTS as developental, they marked 17.10 as developmental due to the sheer number of changes, or as they have shortened the support for non-LTS or, if it is an oversight on days and chaos surrounding release day.